# Как выйти из аккаунта на ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: stackoverflow

Как выйти из аккаунта на ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: очистить localstorage браузера

Comment: Если по теме, то в меню, которое открывается на кнопку `≡` (в правом верхнем углу) есть кнопка "выйти".

Comment: Главное никогда не заходите в Vi, а то так и застрянете.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это ж облачко, а не бургер.

Comment: @Qwertiy для него есть юникод символ более подходящий?

Comment: @älёxölüt, не знаю, вряд ли. Но я читая комментарий сразу подумал: "там нет такого символа" и начал скроллить к шапке, чтобы посмотреть :)

Comment: ... и обнаружил. Облбургер!

Comment: @Qwertiy, шапка прибита к верху, не надо никуда скроллить! Ну если только глазами

Comment: @АндрейNOP А у меня не прибита. Вроде в настройках где-то отключается...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я отключил в настройках, как только они это сделали.

Comment: Что же всё никто выйти-то не может. [И поиском не пользуется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%20%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8%20%d0%b8%d0%b7%20%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0).